# JMX polling or TCP Pushing: What is better?

Tags: java, performance, tcp, jmx

I have to implement a monitoring solution.
For this reason a MetricsMicroService has to collect metric data from other microservices. Every minute and for each server, a metricsMicroService has to collect data from 4-6 other microservices and save it to the database. 
Now my question is: What is the most performant way to transfer metric data?
From my point of view there is the choice between the following solutions:

- polling the data via JMX
- pushing to a WebSocket via TCP

Does anybody have some advice?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would do what ever is simplest. If you were doing this once per second, it still wouldn't matter which is most performant, if you are doing this once per milli-second, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to prefer the push model since I can gather all the JMX stats locally, compress them into a payload and make one transmission to an external listener, rather than make several calls into the JVM from a remote. Having said that, a few non-standard JMX clients support request batching (e.g. [Jolokia](https://jolokia.org/)) and then it's 3 of one, a quarter dozen of another. (Not sure if Jolokia compresses, but one of it's deployments is as a WAR so it's probably not difficult to make it do so.)